# Highchart: how to update a dynamic chart by clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I intend to have a button on my web page so that upon clicking a button, a point will be added to a chart **without redrawing the whole chart** (the chart is a modified version of this http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update). However, my current code is not working.

Here is the code in concern: http://jsfiddle.net/wtvaz9gc/7/

```
var series;

$(function drawCharts(numberOfPoint) {
                    // if(typeof chartData == undefined){
                    //  chartData = $(dataStore.getXml());
                    // }

                    $("#b").click(function(){
            series.addPoint([3,3]);
                })
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        Highcharts.setOptions({
                            global: {
                                useUTC: false
                            }
                        });

                        $('#container').highcharts({
                            chart: {
                                type: 'line',
                                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                                marginRight: 10,
                                events: {
                                    load: function () {
                                        series = this.series[0];
                                        // window.myGlobal1 = this.series[0].data[this.series[0].data.length - 1].y;
                                        // console.log(window.myGlobal1 + " " + this.series[0].data[this.series[0].data.length - 1].y);
                                    },
                                }
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: '' 
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                title: {
                                   text: 'Jahre'
                                },
                            //    gridLineWidth: 0,
                             //   lineWidth:1,
                                startOnTick: true,
                                tickPixelInterval: 40,
                                min: 0,
                                max: 10,
                                plotLines: [{
                                    value: 0,
                                    width: 1,
                                    color: '#808080'
                                }]
                            },

                            yAxis: {
                                title: {
                                    text: 'Vermögen(in EUR)'
                                },
                                labels: {
                                    enabled: true
                                },
                                min: 0,
                                max: 100,
                                plotLines: [{
                                    value: 0,
                                    width: 1,
                                    color: '#808080'
                                }]
                            },
                            tooltip: {
                                enabled : false,
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                                }
                            },
                            legend: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            exporting: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            series: [{
                                name: 'Random data',
                                data: ($(function () {
                                // generate an array of random data
                                var data = [],
                                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                                i, preValue;

                                for (i = 0; i < numberOfPoint; i += 1) {
                                    if(i == 0){
                                        data.push({
                                            x: i,
                                            y: 10
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        data.push({
                                            x: i,
                                            y: chartData["wealth"][0][i]
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                                // showMsg(data);
                                // console.log(data);
                                return data;
                            }()))
                            }]
                        });
                    });
                });
```

When I tries to run it in chrome, I got the following error report:
highcharts.js:Uncaught TypeError: i.splice is not a function
addPoint    @   highcharts.js:...

How should I use the function "addPoint" in this case?
Or should I use other method to achieve the purpose?

Comment: Check your console there is some error :  ReferenceError: chartData is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I will fix that.

Comment: Tell us when you did that.

Comment: The code in the link is fixed now. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You have problem in function where you are making data for initial chart. I am not sure if you need it in this form, you had already document.ready() in your code. When you will delete it your chart will work: http://jsfiddle.net/wtvaz9gc/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with the function generating your initial data, but addPoint is working fine:

```js
var series;

$(function drawCharts(numberOfPoint) {
      // if(typeof chartData == undefined){
      //  chartData = $(dataStore.getXml());
      // }

      $("#b").click(function(){
                series.addPoint([10,10]);
                
        })
      $(document).ready(function () {
       Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
         useUTC: false
        }
       });

       $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
         type: 'line',
                   animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                   marginRight: 10,
                   events: {
                    load: function () {
                     series = this.series[0];
                       // window.myGlobal1 = this.series[0].data[this.series[0].data.length - 1].y;
                       // console.log(window.myGlobal1 + " " + this.series[0].data[this.series[0].data.length - 1].y);
                      },
                     }
                    },
                    title: {
                     text: '' 
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                     title: {
                      text: 'Jahre'
                  },
              //    gridLineWidth: 0,
               //   lineWidth:1,
                     startOnTick: true,
                     tickPixelInterval: 40,
                     min: 0,
                     max: 10,
                     plotLines: [{
                      value: 0,
                      width: 1,
                      color: '#808080'
                     }]
                    },

                    yAxis: {
                     title: {
                      text: 'Vermögen(in EUR)'
                     },
                     labels: {
                enabled: true
            },
                     min: 0,
                     max: 100,
                     plotLines: [{
                      value: 0,
                      width: 1,
                      color: '#808080'
                     }]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                     enabled : false,
                     formatter: function () {
                      return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                      Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                      Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                     }
                    },
                    legend: {
                     enabled: false
                    },
                    exporting: {
                     enabled: false
                    },
                    series: [{
                     name: 'Random data',
                     data: [1,2,3]
                    }]
                   });
      });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

   <button id="b" href="#" >AddPoints</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just realized that I overcomplicated stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do in your `series.data` function but removing all that code and defining your chart in your click event so it knows what `series` is does add the point `[3,3]`.

Series declaration now:

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Random data',
    data: []
  }]
```

And the click function (no moved after the chart code):

```
  $("#b").click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.series[0].addPoint([3, 3]);
  })
```

Live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/cb7xe23o/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just realized that I overcomplicated stuff.