# Highchart series style on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, highcharts

I am using Highcharts library (spline chart) to show some data and I have multiple series in that chart and few buttons outside of the chart.

Now on click of any button, I want to show that particular series as selected (may be some different styles or opacity).

For example: I have 3 series and 3 buttons, on click of the first button I want to select the first series and so on.

I an using React with Highcharts library.

Any Suggestions?

I already tried to use `className` but I had to redraw the graph which is not the way I want. Is there anyway to do this without redrawing the graph?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highchart: how to update a dynamic chart by clicking on a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788146/highchart-how-to-update-a-dynamic-chart-by-clicking-on-a-button)

Comment: Chceck out the official demos for `Series.update` function: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Answer (score 0):

You can make a few buttons in html and link these to your highcharts.

This is the function you should use for it:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function () {
    chart.update({
        series: [{
                data: [] // new data array here
       }]
    });
});
```

Highcharts has a demo using buttons to update their chart type, located [here](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/chart-update) in case you want some more information about buttons and chart styling.